# Label images based on user inputs by Python

Tags: python

I have 1000 images which belong to either category 1 or 2. I want to iterate them and label them manually.

For example, once I start running the code, the first image pops out, I press 'Enter' it falls into category 1 or press 'Esc' it fall into category 2. Then the image will close automatically and next image will pops out...this process keep repeating until it reaches last image.

Does anyone have any suggestion on which package can I use? Currently, I only find tkinter. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with tkinter? It seems like it should fulfill your requirements.

Comment: That's great! I never used tkinter before. I want to make sure it is the right package I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenCV for that purpose as well.

```
import cv2

for img in images:
    cv2.imshow("Please select category", img)

    # wait until key pressed
    key = cv2.waitKey()

    # esc key
    if key == 27:
        cat = 2
    else:
        cat = 1

# close all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```